# Will shared memory across threads get corrupted if only one thread uses mutex?

Tags: c, multithreading, shared-memory

I have a situation where I need to access a variable in shared memory across threads. The variable is initially defined and continually updated, in existing code in numerous places. I'm adding code that will allow this existing code base to be run as a background thread, but I need to read data from this shared variable.

My question is do I need to add a mutex to the existing code base every time it's updated? Or can I just add a mutex to the new code for the times when I'm reading the data. I created the following small test case below that seems to workout.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct my_data {

    int shared;

}MY_DATA;

MY_DATA data;
pthread_mutex_t lock;


void *background(void *x_void_ptr)
{
    int i = 0;
    int sleep_time;
    while(i < 10)
    {

        data.shared++;

        printf("BACK thread, Data = %d\n", data.shared);

        sleep_time = rand()%5;
        sleep(sleep_time);
        i++;
    }


    return NULL;

}

int main()
{


    int sleep_time;
    pthread_t bg_thread;


    if(pthread_create(&bg_thread, NULL, background, NULL)) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;

    }

    MY_DATA *p_data = &data;

    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        printf("FOR thread, Data = %d\n", p_data->shared);


        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        sleep_time = rand()%5;
        sleep(sleep_time);

        i++;
    }



    // Finish up
    if(pthread_join(bg_thread, NULL)) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
        return 2;

    }


    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
FOR thread, Data = 0
BACK thread, Data = 1
BACK thread, Data = 2
FOR thread, Data = 2
FOR thread, Data = 2
BACK thread, Data = 3
BACK thread, Data = 4
BACK thread, Data = 5
FOR thread, Data = 5
BACK thread, Data = 6
BACK thread, Data = 7
BACK thread, Data = 8
FOR thread, Data = 8
FOR thread, Data = 8
BACK thread, Data = 9
FOR thread, Data = 9
BACK thread, Data = 10
FOR thread, Data = 10
FOR thread, Data = 10
FOR thread, Data = 10
```

After running this a number of times it looks like there is no data corruption (i.e foreground is reading the correct data), but my instincts are saying that I need to have the mutex in both the foreground and background code.

Comment: You might want to re-read on the concept of a mutex.

Comment: Using a mutex from just one thread makes no sense. So either you don't need it or you have done it wrong. Maybe you should review what a mutex is for.

Comment: Note that all global memory in a process (except thread-local storage, and the local variables in functions) is shared between threads.  Shared memory is a term for memory shared between processes.  Whether the memory is being accessed by threads or processes, you need to ensure that access is properly managed (e.g. with mutexes) whenever there's more than one thread of execution accessing the same memory at the same time.

Comment: Mut-Ex is derived from "Mutual Exclusion": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks this answers it. I suspected that the answer was I needed it in all the parts of the code, but I was trying to be lazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring material from my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222241/will-shared-memory-across-threads-get-corrupted-if-only-one-thread-uses-mutex#comment60075964_36222241) into an answer.*</sup>

Note that all global memory in a process (except thread-local storage, and the local variables in functions) is shared between threads. Shared memory is a term for memory shared between processes.

Whether the memory is being accessed by threads or processes, you need to ensure that access is properly managed (e.g. with mutexes) whenever there's more than one thread of execution that could be accessing the same memory at the same time.  These days, it is seldom safe to assume you have a single core at work in a machine, so potential concurrent access is the norm.

Answer (score -2):

No, your memory won't be corrupted, reading doesn't have any influence on that.
But you'll read in an inconsistent state, which is just as bad.

Comment: yeah you guys are confirming what I thought. Like I mentioned before I was trying to be lazy and not have to heavily modify this existing code base where it accesses this data structure many many times. Thanks for the response.